# Lua - Hex to float

Tags: lua, hex

The hexadecimal value of `0x40130020` is a float value of `2.296883`, using this site http://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/. How can this be implemented to Lua? If I use:

```
x = 0x40130020
print(x)
```

then the result `1074987040` is printed of course... What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily in Lua 5.3:

```
x=0x40130020
s=string.pack("i4",x)
f=string.unpack("f",s)
print(f)
```

`string.pack` and `string.unpack` are new in Lua 5.3.

In previous versions, you'll need an external library written in C or dive into the innards of the IEEE float representation (which is not too hard). See for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886447/convert-signed-ieee-754-float-to-hexadecimal-representation).

Comment: In older versions than 5.3? =|